# Colorised highlighting in ls command

Tags: shell, ubuntu, ls, ls-colors

When doing ls on my Ubuntu 15.10 machine, I get a colorised highlighting for directories.[image: This is what happens]

How can I remove this highlighting?

Answer (score 3):

I guess `ls` is an alias on Ubuntu - you can check that by executing `alias ls` in a terminal.
Try `unalias ls` in a terminal, afterwards you should see no coloring

Update:
To remove only the highlighting, edit your env. var. `LS_COLORS` e.g. to use the style of Ubuntu 14.04 execute `LS_COLORS="$LS_COLORS:di=01;34"`
For more details you could have a look at [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/466198/how-do-i-change-the-color-for-directories-with-ls-in-the-console) answer.

Note: To add your alias again, execute `alias ls='ls --color=auto'` again

Comment: I did unalias ls and then after doing ls, no coloring at all was there. Is there any way to color only the directories?

Comment: Ah sry, I interpreted it as you wanted to remove the coloring completely. Yea there is a way to remove just the highlighting - I will update my answer.